# too late to filter categories if get categories is onload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure why the filter I'm using doesn't work, if it is too late to filter the categories once they have loaded or if I am just approaching this totally wrong.

Since updateAvailableMusic() runs onload, and filterAvailableCateories() gets run onclick from the html file as such :

"ng-click='filterAvailableCategories(party)'"

I am wondering if I need to be passing more information to the filter function. And as this is Angular and I don't really understand how to debug Angular (read: "follow it through with a breakpoint the way I would normal javascript", I am hoping to get another perspective on this and much thanks ahead of time.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.updateAvailableMusic = function () {
    return music.getMusicCategories(null, $scope.featureType).then(function (options) {
        $scope.availableCategoriesUnmapped = options;
        $scope.addDefaultCategories();
        $scope.availableCategories = _.groupBy(options, 'category');
    });
};
$scope.filterAvailableCategories = function (musictype) {

        $scope.availableCategories = $scope.availableCategories.filter(function (rr) {
            switch (musictype) {
            case 'party':
                if (rr.category !== 'Rap' && rr.category !== 'HipHop') {
                    return rr;
                }
                break;
            case 'study':
                if (rr.category !== 'Classical' && rr.category !== 'Jazz') {
                    return rr;
                }
                break;
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: In `ng-click='filterAvailableCategories(party)'`, you are passing a *variable* called `party` - should that be the string `"party"`? Also, as an aside, do you really think good "study" music is everything *except* classical and jazz?

Comment: *"filter doesn't work"* tells us next to nothing and is not a problem statement that anyone can troubleshoot from. Suggest reading [ask] thoroughly then update the question

Comment: can u create a plunker or fiddle for this @rubixkube